# how to show total price in label in rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails

in view code:

```
 <% for item in @cart.line_items %>
   <%= item.quantity*item.product.price %>
 <% end %>
```

I want to get the total price after calculation and show in a label.

Answer (score 3):

```
@cart.line_items.sum { |item| item.quantity * item.product.price }
```

Comment: wrong number of arguments (1 for 2):                                                          <%= @cart.line_items.sum { |item| item.quantity * item.product.price }%>